# How to dynamically change div text of a dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Apologies for asking something already answered. I have tried to resolve this but i am unable to get this working(Might be because i am not a javascript guy and it confuses me.)

I want to change text of a div which is generated dynamically from a js library that i am using for show error messages.

I have tried to change the element using jQuery by its class like

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.error-message')[item_number].innerText.replace('old string','new string');
}
```

I have tried checking if the element is undefined and put a condition for that and also tried to use simple javascript. But i think the problem is not that, but that the function is not running dynamically and changing the values on the fly as this works in js console.

I would appreciate if someone answers what i need to learn and use for this. I don't think this needs ajax and i should be able to do this via pure js or jquery. But please let me know if i need the delve deeper into ajax to handle this.

Please note that i am able to change the text in js console as i want. Its just the i am unable to handle this on the fly as the div which i am trying to change is also generated on the fly.

Comment: Instead of `.innerText`, try using `.text()`.

Comment: the string `replace()` method doesn't change the original string, it returns a new string.

Comment: Is the text in the DOM at the time you are trying to change it? If its dynamic and hasn't loaded yet you will need to wait for the text to be present before trying to manipulate it.

Comment: @doutriforce Thanks for reply. I had tried that. I am more concerned if its something that the library not letting me do it or not As both `innerText` and `.text()` works in console but not working on the fly.

Comment: @RajatVij, no problem. Can you post your html, please? And have a look at Kris's suggestion.

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck Yes. It is dynamic and i need to wait for the text to be present before trying to manipulate it. That's exactly where i am stuck

Comment: Does this other JS library provide a call back or like an after data loaded function where you can do some stuff? The hackiest way (but not recommended) would be wrapping your code in a `setTimeout`

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, isn't `$(document).load()` an option?

Comment: @doutriforce, I don't believe that would work in this scenario. `.load()` is for loading external content. Similar to AJAX.. But in this case the external content is loaded via some third party script. (so the part that could essentially use .load() is not contrlled by the OP). And the OP wants to manipulate that loaded data after the third party script is finished. So I think what we need is more detail as to how the data is being loaded. And or more info about the thirdparty script. This would typically be handled with a callback, or a promise or something along those lines.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, i always thought that this event was used to run codes _after_ the page had been completely loaded. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @doutriforce, It use to be that way in older jquery versions. But that was deprecated. It is used this way now..  https://api.jquery.com/load/. Here is the deprecated way https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think i can work this out using `setTimeout`. Sorry i got busy so couldn't try any solution. Will update once any solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery - this should work for you.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.error-message')[item_number].text('new string');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla js code would be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[item_number].innerHTML = "something else here"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```js
$(function()
{
  $('.add_div').click(function(event)
  {
    // Dynamically add div
    var $new_div = $('<div class="new_div"/>').text('default text');

    // Prepend so you don't have to scroll to see the div update
    $('.div_container').prepend($new_div);
    flash_first_div();
  });

  $('.update_text').click(function(event)
  {
    var date = new Date(),
        hour = date.getHours(),
        minutes = date.getMinutes(),
        seconds = date.getSeconds();

    // UPDATE LAST DYNAMICALLY CREATED DIV
    $('.new_div').first().text('text updated at ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    flash_first_div();
  });
  
  // Just a helper function to highlight the targeted div
  function flash_first_div()
  {
    var $last_div = $('.new_div').first();
    
    $last_div.addClass('flash');

    window.setTimeout(function(){$last_div.removeClass('flash');},500);
  };
});
```

```css
button{font-size:16px}
div{transition: background 1s;margin-bottom:10px}
.new_div{padding:0.5em;border:1px solid #000000}
.flash{background:yellow}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id='buttons'>
  <button class='add_div'>Add Div</button>
  <button class='update_text'>Update text of last created div</button>
</div>
<div class='div_container'></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```